# What happened to the CDS vs Tian controversy?

Tags: ho.history-overview

May I ask what is the status of the CDS *versus* Tian controversy on K-stability? Our mathematical community cannot tolerate people who plagiarize or fabricate stories to promote their career. I know both side has papers published in respectable journals already. Which side is right? Which side is wrong? What do we know now?

Comment: Whatever the merits of this case, the mathematical community seems incapable of policing itself. It's very depressing.

Comment: Since I had no idea what the "CDS vs Tian controversy" was, I found this description by googling: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=6430 (I have no idea whether it is biased, of course, it's just the first link that popped up).

Comment: Paper of Tian has been published in highly ranking journal here http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.21578/abstract I have read both of the papers. Proofs are completely different. Also The main question was Kahler-Einstein metric is equivalent to CM stability of Tian. And this solved only by Gang Tian . Also Odaka trying to extend this result to Arithmetic version and he couldn't do it yet

Comment: This question is in essence asking about a political outcome in a mathematical arena.  If this question is suitable for StackExchange at all, I believe it belongs at academia, not here.  If the post is modified to ask about the mathematics and not the politics, then it might be suitable here.  If this post remains, in my view the **only** acceptable answer to the (at this writing) posted questions is a link to discussion elsewhere.  I strongly believe such discussion is antithetical to this forum.  Gerhard "Priority Fights Don't Belong Here" Paseman, 2016.02.26.

Comment: I agree. I suggest that the question be reposted purely as a mathematical question (perhaps asking for a comparison between the two proofs), without words such as controversy, plagiarism, fabricate.

Comment: math-education-history? Odd choice for a tag.